# Year wrapping on 2013-12-31

Tags: sql

Consider the case when today is 2013-12-31, but the customer's birthday is on 2014-01-01
The first predicate will return 2013-01-01, which the next predicate will not match within its next 7 days range. How do I fix that?
Thanks

```
 select c.CustomerCode AS 会员ID, c.LastName || ' ' ||  c.FirstName AS 姓名, c.MobilePhoneNumber AS 手机号码 from 
   customer  c 
   where  

  { fn  TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4)))} || '-' ||
  { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.DOB)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) } || '-' ||
  { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(DAY(c.DOB) AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) }
       BETWEEN cast({ fn DATE(CURRENT_DATE) } as date)   
     AND cast ({ fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,  +7 ,   CURRENT_DATE) } as date)   
         group by c.CustomerCode, c.LastName, c.FirstName, c.MobilePhoneNumber";
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I want to get a 7 day prior alerts for customers' birthday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming that the next birthday is in the current calendar year. There is no need to make such an assumption. You're also assuming that the combination of month/day exists in the current calendar year, which is not necessarily true, as a birthday might be on Feb 29.

Both of these can be easily avoided. Take the difference between `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)` and `YEAR(DOB)`. Suppose that's 18. Now add 18 years to `DOB` (which might change Feb 29 to a different date of the year), and you've got this year's birthday for the customer. Compare that to `CURRENT_DATE`. If it's earlier, the birthday has already passed, and the next birthday is actually 18+1 years after `DOB`. If it's later, the birthday has yet to pass, and you've already got the next birthday.

Now that you've determined the next birthday, you can take the difference between `CURRENT_DATE` and that.

Note that nowhere in this process do dates need to be manipulated as strings.

The precise details on how to express this in SQL vary based on the SQL dialect you're using. It's also not clear to me whether it's a good idea to write this in SQL at all. You can determine what makes most sense for your use.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is logical